# Gap between textbook and input type button using Bootstrap input group on MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem when my view render, i am using a input group class to join a textbox and a input but the problem is that if you see they doesn't get together, i already find a solution that is to erase part of the 'site.css' mvc project make from default but that  doesn't work for me.
here is my code.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default" />
        </span>
        Product name: @Html.TextBox("id", null, new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
}
```

[and its views like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSrr6.png)

Comment: Can you paste the generated HTML?

Comment: </p><form action="/Products/Index" method="post">        <div class="input-group">
            Product name: <input class="form-control" id="id" name="id" type="text" value="">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default">
            </span>
        </div>
</form>    <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the width of the `div`.

UPDATE:

I am confused on why your `TextBox` and `Label`(Product Name) are below the `span`.

Here is a working [example](http://www.bootply.com/0BJxl3F58x) with `add-ons` on both sides:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Input addons</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @FedericoM.VonMühlinen what happens when you put the label and textbox *above* the `span`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that "Product name:" falls inside the input-group but isn't in a input group compatible tag. Here is a plunker with some options. [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JcGxnTX38mS0WgjrYWq7?p=preview)

```
<form action="/Products/Index" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"> Product name:</span>
      <input class="form-control" id="id" name="id" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default" />
        </span>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form action="/Products/Index" method="post">
    <label>Product name:</label>
    <div class="input-group">      
      <input class="form-control" id="id" name="id" type="text" value="" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default" />
        </span>
    </div>
  </form>
```